# How to change the behavior of dropdown buttons in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a menu which has buttons as menu items. One of the menu items is a drop down button. I am coding in Bootstrap and CSS. Everything is working fine except when I click on one of the dropdown menu items. When I do that, the drop down button called "More" goes green and the word "More" disappears, so all I see is just a green opaque button. I have made the text outline of the "More" button green so it's picking up the color from that. Otherwise, when a menu dropdown item link has not been clicked, the color of the button is black. The links for the dropdown menu items themselves are changing to the right color so there are no problems in that part.

This is the code for the menu:

```css
.button-primary-override:hover, 
.button-primary-override:active, 
.button-primary-override:focus,
.button-primary-override:visited {
  background: rgba(0, 0 ,0 ,0.3) !important;
}
.button-primary-override a:hover,
.button-primary-override a:active, 
.button-primary-override a:focus,
.button-primary-override a:visited {
  background: rgba(0, 0 ,0 ,0.3) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row pl-4 pr-4 pt-2 pb-1 myBanner d-block"> 
  <div class="content d-flex">
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light" style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light" style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light" style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill dropup">
      <button type="button" class="btn text-success btn-outline-success button-primary-override dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="font-size:16px">More</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu myBanner2 mb-1">
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Ideally a black button with the word "More" written on it should appear when the user clicks a dropdown menu item.

Actually, I don't really mind the color - green is acceptable if it's easier to keep it that color, but I want to make the button transparent and the word "More" to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by not using Bootstrap's property of "button-outline". I removed `button-outline-success` from the class, and I added the outline using CSS. I followed the instructions from [w3schools - Outline Buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_outline_buttons) to make the outline around the button.

The css is:

```
.button-primary-override {
  border: 1px solid #5cb85c;
  color: #5cb85c;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}  

.button-primary-override:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #5cb85c;
}
```

and the html is:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row pl-4 pr-4 pt-2 pb-1 myBanner d-block"> 
  <div class="content d-flex">
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light" style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light" style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn text-light" style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill dropup">
      <div class="flex-fill dropup"><button type="button" class="btn button-primary-override dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="font-size:16px;">More</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu myBanner2 mb-1">
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I click a dropdown menu item, the button's background becomes a slightly transparent black and the text "More" (in green color) remains visible on the button. When nothing is clicked, you see a button with "More" on it on a transparent black background and you can see a green outline around the button. (I chose hex color code #5cb85c so that it would emulate the green of Bootstrap's "success" color.)

So I think the reason for the behavior of the button turning an opaque green and the text disappearing was the "button-outline-success" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you want. You are not simply elaborate your question.
this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_buttons.asp) will also helped you

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row pl-4 pr-4 pt-2 pb-1 myBanner d-block"> 
  <div class="content d-flex">
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn " style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn " style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill pb-1">
      <a type="button" class="btn " style="font-size:16px" href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="font-size:16px">More</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu myBanner2 mb-1">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works if I use as is. But as soon as I add "text-success btn-outline-success" to the class of the button "More", the behavior of the button goes back to what it was as described in the question: the button turns green and the word "More" disappears when a menu dropdown item is clicked. @Ammad Amir

Comment: text-success is bootstrap class for green color text when you use this class it will turns your text in green color even if you hovered on button 

check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_colors.asp) for bootstrap text color

Comment: Yes, I know "success" = green. It doesn't explain why the text "More" disappears and why the whole buttton's background color goes green, not just the outline or the text. @Ammad Amir